# A hash inside an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this hash:

```
{"id" => [323, 324], info => ["Test Info", "Test Info2"]}
```

I would like to have a hash inside an array like this:

```
array = [
  [{"id" => "323", info => "Test Info"}],
  [{"id" => "324", info => "Test Info2"}]
]
```

I have duplicate data. I need to use `uniq` on `id` and `info` to get each `id` only once. Because of that, I need to join them afterwards.

Comment: "*I have duplicate data*" - show it!

Comment: *"Because of that, I need to join them afterwards"* - are you sure? Removing duplicates from one array (the joined one) seems easier.

Comment: Speaking of "one array" -  do you really want hashes nested in an array within another array? That seems to be one level too much.

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {"id" => [323, 324], "info" => ["Test Info", "Test Info2"]}

h.map { |k, v| [k].product v }.transpose.map &:to_h

#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#      "id" => 323,
#    "info" => "Test Info"
#  },
#  [1] {
#      "id" => 324,
#    "info" => "Test Info2"
#  }
]
```

If you want to wrap each nested hash into it’s own array, one more action is required:

```
h.map { |k, v| [k].product v }.transpose.map(&:to_h).map { |e| [e] }

#⇒ [
#  [0] [
#    [0] {
#        "id" => 323,
#      "info" => "Test Info"
#    }
#  ],
#  [1] [
#    [0] {
#        "id" => 324,
#      "info" => "Test Info2"
#    }
#  ]
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution (maybe so OP in this case)

```
h = {"id" => [323, 324], "info" => ["Test Info", "Test Info2"]}

h.values.transpose.map do |a|
  [Hash[h.keys.each_with_index.map { |k, i| [k, a[i]] }]]
end

# => [[{"id"=>323, "info"=>"Test Info"}], [{"id"=>324, "info"=>"Test Info2"}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) which zippers together two arrays:

```
hash = {
  "id" => [323, 324],
  "info" => ["Test Info", "Test Info2"]
}

keys = %w[ id info ]

array = hash['id'].zip(hash['info']).map do |id, info|
  Hash[keys.zip(pair)]
end

# => [{"id"=>323, "info"=>"Test Info"}, {"id"=>324, "info"=>"Test Info2"}]
```

The [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) method is used to convert an array of form `[['a',1],['b',2]]` to a hash of form `{'a'=>1,'b'=>2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple more:

```
h = {"id" => [323, 324], "info" => ["Test Info", "Test Info2"]}

da_keys = h.keys
h.values.transpose.each_with_object([]) { |a,b| b << da_keys.zip(a).to_h }
  #=> [{"id"=>323, "info"=>"Test Info"}, {"id"=>324, "info"=>"Test Info2"}] 

rolling_keys = h.keys.cycle
h.values.transpose.map {|a| a.each_with_object({}) {|v,g| g.update(rolling_keys.next=>v)}}
  #=> [{"id"=>323, "info"=>"Test Info"}, {"id"=>324, "info"=>"Test Info2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for this:

```
array = [
  [{"id" => "323", info => "Test Info"}],
  [{"id" => "324", info => "Test Info2"}]
]
```

But I assume what you really want is just this:

```
array = [
  {"id" => "323", "info" => "Test Info"},
  {"id" => "324", "info" => "Test Info2"}
]
```

Given this:

```
h = {"id" => [323, 324], "info" => ["Test Info", "Test Info2"]}
```

You can do this:

```
h.map { |k,l| l.map { |v| [ k,v ] } }.reduce(&:zip).map(&:to_h)
```